# New class definition and scope resolution operator

Tags: ruby

I make a simple Ruby class as follows in a Ruby script:

```
class Rock::Stone
end
```

When I run the script at the command prompt, I get:

```
`<main>': uninitialized constant Rock (NameError)
```

Why is this?  I thought scope resolution operators were allowed in class defs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought scope resolution operators were allowed in class defs?

They are allowed, but the containing module (or class) must exist first:

```
module Rock
end

class Rock::Stone
end

Rock::Stone.new
# => #<Rock::Stone:0x00000000a38248>
```

Answer (score 0):

The encapsulating module/class must be declared first. Try this:

```
module Rock
  class Stone
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to create a class or module `Rock` first, then `Rock::Stone` can exist.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195661/ruby-when-to-use-nested-classes-and-classes-nested-in-modules) SO thread may help.